# Wordpress Anchor link to another page in a specific element

Tags: php, html, wordpress, anchor

I am working with the anchor link to another page in a specific element id. I have these two optional codes but these two doesn't work. when I see the link on the programmer view, the link is right and it works fine. but when I try to click from the menu navbar it doesn't link and nothing happened. here are the two optional codes I have using so far:

```
<a href="<?php echo home_url( '/#aboutus' ); ?>">About Us</a>
```

and

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>#aboutus">About Us</a>
```

basically my goal is from top page anchor to another page in a specific element id. and from another page anchor it to top page in a specific element id. is there any ways how to achieve this anchor link?

Comment: What is the value returned by the home_url function above, or what is the actual html rendered in the browser when you use the functions above? Do you actually have a section or element with the id "aboutus"? Based on the code the href attribute should have this value `https://example.com/#aboutus`.

Comment: hi @issmael yes I have id on the specific element from another page.

Comment: is this the only way that we can use?

Answer (score 0):

You should do your code like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/aboutus">About Us</a>
```

or

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>/aboutus">About Us</a>
```

Comment: hi @ZealousWeb thank you for your codes however your code didn't work either

Comment: is this the only way that we can use?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) . "#aboutus"; ?>">About Us</a>
```

Comment: hi @iismael unfortunately your code didn't work either. I was too confusing, all our codes are perfectly working fine when I checked on the programming windows, I saw all our codes are link right, even I clicked the link from the source code are all working fine. but when I tried to click on the menu tab at the top page menu, our codes doesn't recognized and didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this on home page then you should do like this:

```
<a href="#aboutus">About Us</a>
```

OR

You want to do for inner page you should do like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/inner page slug/#aboutus">About Us</a>
```

Comment: hi @ZealousWeb unfortunately the code didn't work again